# Replacing thermocouple with thermopile

Tags: boiler

I'm having huge issues finding a replacement thermocouple for my Kenmore 153332421 boiler. It seems that Sears is the only place to get them. I ordered one a couple of days ago but after receiving the package I noticed they shipped thermopile. Both parts seem to have the same number. I've been checking the manual but there is no mention of thermocouple. Any idea if thermopile serves as both parts in this model?

Thanks

Comment: A thermopile produces more electric current than a thermocouple and have different electrical connections.. If the connector on the thermopile is the same as the old thermocouple, probably would work. Search Amazon for the part. I have gotten hard to find / discontinued parts from there.

Comment: @gunner that should be an answer , I agree it will work if it connects the same.+

Answer (score 1):

A thermopile produces more electric current than a thermocouple and have different electrical connections.. If the connector on the thermopile is the same as the old thermocouple, probably would work. Search Amazon for the part. I have gotten hard to find / discontinued parts from there.

Comment: Yes, a thermopile is just a collection of thermocouples in a single unit. I have seen these terms (incorrectly) used interchangeably in product literature...